# NSOutlineView+NSTreeNode: where's my custom data gone?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm setting up a NSOutlineView bound to a NSTreeController that's populated with `NSTreeNode` instances, the latter having my custom NodeData objects attached using `[NSTreeNode treeNodeWithRepresentedObject:...]`.
The outline view renders just fine, all data's there as expected, all good.

Now in the outline view's delegate I'm trying to change the render style via a
`outlineView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:item:` method.

However, the `item` parameter will not give me back my custom data!

```
id stuff = [item representedObject];
```

yields an instance of class `NSTreeNode` where item is a `NSTreeControllerTreeNode`.

What the heck is going on?
According to all documentation and sample code I could find the representedObject call should give me the `NodeData` object back I've stuffed into the NSTreeNode when building the tree..

Totally clueless as I seem to be the only person having this problem so I must be doing something really stupid somewhere - but I can't see what's wrong with the code.

Populating the tree controller programmatically using `setContent:[dataSource sillyHack]`
with this trivial content shows the same behavior:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) sillyHack
{
   NSMutableArray *nodeArray = [NSMutableArray array];

   NodeData *scaleTypeListNode = [[NodeData alloc] initWithName:@"123"];
   NSTreeNode *scaleTypeListTreeNode = [NSTreeNode treeNodeWithRepresentedObject:scaleTypeListNode];
   [scaleTypeListNode release];

   [nodeArray addObject:scaleTypeListTreeNode];
   return nodeArray;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should populate NSTreeController with you own data instances, not NSTreeNode.